# How to reconnect when xmpp server stops

Tags: android, xmpp

I want to connect to server when my XMPP server(ejabberd) restarts after a while staying in a STOP state.
I am thinking about to send a connection request to server after a particular time interval. So that i could know the server has been restarted.
What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for me would be using google cloud messaging service GCM, as sending request to server will drain more battery and network data.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: I am making a chat application. So, the problem is persistent.

Comment: if the server is stopped then you cant connect to it from device. Handle this situation in device itself, like trying to connect in exponential time periods.

Comment: yes when the server stops, and you try to connect form the server it will give you exception, but when the server restart you notify all android devices that i am back and now you can access me. so periodic connection checking can be omitted.